# Python, ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

Iam getting an value error(ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) at the line for pcolormesh, any idea how to handle this.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

data = np.loadtxt('out.txt')
lats = data[:,0]
lons = data[:,1]
codg_tec = data[:,2]

m = Basemap(projection = 'merc', llcrnrlon= -9, llcrnrlat=19, urcrnrlon= 12, urcrnrlat=37,       resolution= 'i')
m.drawcoastlines()

lon = np.all(lons)
lat = np.all(lats)

x, y = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)

lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
x, y = m(lon, lat)

cb = m.pcolormesh(x, y, codg_tec, shading='flat', cmap=plt.cm.jet)
m.colorbar(location ='right')
cbar = m.colorbar(cb, location = 'right', pad = '10%')

m.drawmapboundary()
m.drawmapscale()
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-9,12,5), labels=[False,False,False,True])
m.drawparallels(np.arange(19,38,5), labels=[True,False,False,False])
m.drawstates()
m.drawcountries()

plt.title('CODG-vTEC on 02-01-2015')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [`matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html) documentation:

`[x,y]` is required (a `list`)

```py
cb = m.pcolormesh([x, y], codg_tec, shading='flat', cmap=plt.cm.jet)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i get another error!!!!:                                                       Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "color.py", line 21, in <module>
    cb = m.pcolormesh([x, y], codg_tec, shading='flat', cmap=plt.cm.jet)
TypeError: with_transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'

Comment: This is also in the link - do a find for "data" on the page.

Comment: Ah it's true, it didn't work in the first try ^^' , il worked this way  "cb = m.pcolormesh(x, y, data[codg_tec] , shading='flat', cmap=plt.cm.jet) ", but the errors follow me, i get this error : IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,
`cb, your_arg = m.pcolormesh(x, y, codg_tec, shading='flat', cmap=plt.cm.jet)`