# Plotting the height, Z, as a function of coordinates X,Y in 2D using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataset existing of coordinates X,Y with an associated height measurement at that coordination, e.g.

```
X1 Y1 Z1
X2 Y2 Z2
...
```

and I would like to create a 2D plot which shows the height as a colour (heat map). Currently I am trying to do this through numpy pcolormesh, however I have trouble feeding the data in a correct manner to the function: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1).

What am I doing wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

thickness = np.genfromtxt('data.txt')

x=thickness[:,0]
y=thickness[:,1]
z=thickness[:,2]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.pcolormesh(x,y,z, shading='auto')
#cbar = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: First, of, you will need to add `plt.show()` at the end, otherwise your result won't be visualised.

Comment: Second, could you replace `thickness[:, 0]` with some dummy arrays ( a few elements will do) and run your code, to make sure you can get a picture?

Comment: `pcolormesh` needs its parameters in a *meshed* form.  If your values aren't meshed, you could create a scatter plot: `ax.scatter(x, y, c=z)`.

Comment: See also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62273084/python-valueerror-not-enough-values-to-unpack-expected-2-got-1 for an example how to construct inputs for `pcolormesh`, though note that it highly depends on how your original data is organized.

Comment: Hi @JohanC, this indeed works! But I would like to fill the data in-between to create a height map. This currently only plots the values at the specific coordinates. How would I create a mesh in this case?

Comment: Well, * it highly depends on how your original data is organized*. And it seems you forgot to add reproducible data to your plot...

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the data itself due to NDA's involved for this project. It is an array of (228,3). With the columns being X,Y,Z and the rows being the measurements themselves. The coordinates are somewhat irregularly spaced floats and not integers, which I believe to be the main source of the problem for the height map.

Comment: `ax.tricontourf` might work here

Comment: Thank you very much, ax.tricontourf solved my problems and made me plot the data without too much hassle!